# Prior art in French from YouTube is accepted?

Tags: prior-art, usa

I want to publicize a new invention so that it is available on YT for collaborators and as proof that it is my work, through a discreet page so that not alot of casual researchers will find it. Is it OK to title the video in French, is that of equivalent status in the US as prior art written in English? Can't i be doubted to have published the video on the given day but alleged to have changed the viewing rights to private, when i contend that it has been available since the day of upload?

Comment: You should search this site with the term “defensive publication” for some info on better options than YouTube.

Comment: To prevent other's patenting this, you want patent examiners to find it and cite it in their rejections.